# Improper integrals. Why do I need to use a limit?

Tags: calculus

I understand that the function may not exist at the limits of integration, and therefore, conceptually, the limit makes sense.  You are finding the area as x approaches the discontinuity, but not including it.  Yet, if I just do the problems ignoring the discontinuity, I always get the correct answer anyway.  Just integrate, and do top-bottom and get the value.

[image]
[image]

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

[image]

Comment: "Yet, if I just do the problems ignoring the discontinuity, I always get the correct answer anyway" - and what happens if you try to integrate $\frac1x$ over $[-1,1]$? Still get the right answer?

Comment: I get 0 for the answer when ignoring limits.  What did you get?

Comment: @user170231 based from the title I think the OP isnt talking about why we have to split the improper integral but why we use limits. To which I'd answer 1/infinity isn't zero and 1/0 isn't infinity, at least formally in basic math. When integrating up to a discontinuous point like a jump discontinuity only the limit exists and that's what we mean to use.

Comment: @user170231 Yes, I get the same answer using either method.  I appended my work to the main post above.   0 either way.   So, yes, I still get the right answer.

Comment: @JackOfAll I get $\int_{-1}^1\frac1xdx = 1$, using the (just as valid) antiderivative $$F(x) = \cases{\ln(-x) & if $x<0$\\\ln(x) + 1 & if $x > 0$}$$

Comment: @Arthur The image didn't load on my device. But yeah, also to JackOfAll: as for 1/x, note that an indefinite integral can be interpreted as some amount of accumulation from a given fixed point. Recall that at a point the instantaneous rate of accumulation of area under a function's curve is the functions value at that point. The constant of integration depends on the point where the accumulation starts, and visually it's the area under the curve from that point. The rate of accumulation of values of a function isn't dependant on where you started accumulation, it'll always be the same.

Comment: - the same there. The area under the curve between two points a and b is the difference of the total accumulation from the start to b and from the starting point to a

Comment: It's how much more accumulation has been added. In other words its (F(b)+C)-(F(a)+C), the C's cancel and you have the fundamental theorem of calculus. But this (the FTC) doesn't work if your +C is not the same everywhere, and if so it's as though there's a "jump" in the amount of area, which only (and does) happen at discontinuities. If a function doesn't exist at a point, like in 1/x for instance, it may not be continuable there so the antiderivative F of f may be so too. The contrapositive: if f is discontinuous it's antiderivate may be so too. So the C in plus C only has to be constant when

Comment: Arthur, I don't see how you can get 1 for the area under the curve.  The 1/x graph is symmetric (odd), and the signed areas should "cancel" each other.   Just by looking at the graph, the answer should be zero, not one.

Comment: The function you're integrating is continuous. An antiderivative of is just something whose whose derivative is f, which doesn't mean C is constant. For 1/x it's integral is ln(x)+C, note: no absolute value. Natural log of negatives are imaginary and for convenience we add a different +C to left of LN to remove the imaginary part, leaving us with an absolute value sign in the LN. Because +C is different the FTC fails and just happens to give you a correct value sometimes for 1/x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this example:

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x^2} \; dx = \left.\frac{-1}{x}\right|_{-1}^{1} = -2.$$

If you graph this region, it's area is clearly positive.  But the answer you get by just ignoring the discontinuity is negative.  The actual area is infinite.  So at least in this case, the limit is necessary.

In general, when we write $\infty$, it's shorthand for a limit.  It's common for people who have completed calculus to write things like $f(\infty),$ so it may look like they're ignoring the limit, but they are not.  They have (hopefully) at least thought about whether $f(\infty)$ exists.  For example:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x} \; dx = \left. -e^{-x}\right|_0^\infty = -e^{-\infty} - (-e^{-0}) = 0 +1.$$

You see this sort of calculation a lot, which doesn't have the word "lim" anywhere in sight.  But the (competent) person has given the implicit limit some thought.

Comment: Finally, an example where the "shortcut" does not work!  Thanks!